# knowing the location of the database in the SDCard of Android emulator

Tags: android

If i am creating any database in android, where does it gets stored in the SDCard of the emulator? and also is the database path of the SDCard and the DB path of the device memory different??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Databases are by default stored in internal memory. On a real device like the Droid X, it will be stored somewhere /data/data/package.name.here/databases/dbname.extension

Also, look up [Context.getDatabasePath(..)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDatabasePath%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: okk.. i jst wanted to know                                          database path of the SDCard and the DB path of the device memory different??

Comment: Yes, they are different. internal memory will generally be under `/data/data`, while anything in the sdcard will be under `/sdcard/`

You should NOT assume this, always use APIs like `Environment.getDataDirectory()` and `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to get file paths.

Comment: these APIs is returning the path in a file format..is there any other method to get the path in string format.

Comment: Yes. File has getAbsolutePath()

Answer (score 0):

You can specify an explicit path to the SD card in your openOrCreateDatabase() call.  e.g.

SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("/sdcard/myapp/mydb", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

Just make sure to test that /sdcard exists before you start writing to or reading from it.